# Scaling Physics Bodies in Xcode Spritekit

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

I recently came across an issue where I would increase the size of a node, but the physics body would remain the same size. I tried to look up solutions to this with no success. How can I make the body scale with the size of the node?

```
CGPoint location = CGPointMake(randX, -self.frame.size.height - expander.size.height);

SKAction *moveAction = [SKAction moveTo:location duration:randDuration];

SKAction *expandAction = [SKAction resizeToWidth:(expander.size.width * 1.4) height:(expander.size.width * 1.4) duration:1.0];

SKAction *collapseAction = [SKAction resizeToWidth:(expander.size.width) height: (expander.size.height) duration:1.0];

SKAction *doneAction = [SKAction runBlock:(dispatch_block_t)^() {
    expander.hidden = YES;
}];

SKAction *expandCollapseAction = [SKAction repeatActionForever:[SKAction sequence:@[expandAction, collapseAction]]];

SKAction *moveExpandAction = [SKAction group:@[moveAction, expandCollapseAction]];

SKAction *moveExpanderActionWithDone = [SKAction sequence: @[moveExpandAction, doneAction ]];
[expander runAction:moveExpanderActionWithDone withKey: @"expanderMoving"];
```

Comment: Short answer: you can't, physics shapes don't scale. Longer answer: you would have to recreate the body every frame for the duration of the scale with continuously updated and properly scaled body shape. This however is highly inefficient. Not sure about iOS 8 though, it's possible it works there, at least I vaguely remember something related to scaling physics bodies.

Comment: @LearnCocos2D This is completely unexpected, because I remember that this wasn't worked. But I tried it now, and it looks like it works. Can you please check my answer and give your thoughts ?

Answer (score 5):

I thought this won't work, but it looks like that physics body is scaled after all. Here is the code which can reproduce physics body scaling on iOS8 :

```
- (void)didMoveToView:(SKView *)view {
  /* Setup your scene here */

    SKSpriteNode *s = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithColor:[SKColor yellowColor] size:CGSizeMake(100,100)];
    s.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), CGRectGetMinY(self.frame)+100);
    s.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:s.size];

    s.physicsBody.dynamic = YES;
    
    s.physicsBody.affectedByGravity = NO;

    [self addChild:s];
    
    [s runAction:[SKAction scaleTo:0.3f duration:5]];

    [s.physicsBody applyImpulse:CGVectorMake(0,30)];
  
}
```

If I recall correctly , this wasn't worked earlier, but I just tried it and it looks like it work. Still, this is not fully tested and I am not sure if this will mess up the physics simulation. Contact detection will probably work though. I just wanted to show that actual physics bodies are scaled when sprite is scaled . Here is the result:

[image: scaling physics body]

From the gif above it can be seen that physics body is scaled along with sprite (without re-creating another different sized physics body). The blue bounding box around the sprite is visual representation of sprite's physics body (enabled in view controller with `skView.showsPhysics = YES`);

Comment: If a physics body can be scaled with its node, I wonder if Apple will let us scale a physics body independently without changing the size of its sprite node.

Comment: @peacetype Heaven't tried, but I am pretty positive that there is no method or a property on SKPhysicsBody class for something like that at the moment of speaking.

Comment: True, I'm look at the documentation now and there is nothing for that. I submitted a report to Apple requesting this.

Answer (score -1):

this is strange you can do it  add physics body before adding it to the SKNode or SKScene for e.g.

```
SKTexture  *texture=[_gameTexture textureNamed:@"mysprite"];
SKSpriteNode *bubble=[SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithTexture:texture];
bubble.anchorPoint=CGPointMake(0.5,0.5);
//_bubble.name=[@"bubble" stringByAppendingFormat:@"%d ",index];
bubble.name=newcolor;
```

// _bubble.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
   _bubble.position=CGPointMake(newPosition.x, newPosition.y);

```
//
bubble.physicsBody=[SKPhysicsBody bodyWithCircleOfRadius:60];
bubble.physicsBody.dynamic=NO;
bubble.physicsBody.linearDamping=0;
bubble.physicsBody.restitution=0;


bubble.physicsBody.density=1;
bubble.physicsBody.allowsRotation=NO;
bubble.physicsBody.affectedByGravity=NO;
//_bubble.physicsBody.velocity=CGVectorMake([self getRandomNumberBetween:-10 to:7], [self getRandomNumberBetween:-10 to:7]);
//  _bubble.physicsBody.usesPreciseCollisionDetection=YES;


bubble.physicsBody.categoryBitMask=ballCategory;
bubble.physicsBody.collisionBitMask=ballCategory | pathCategory ;
bubble.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask=ballCategory | pathCategory ;

[self addChild:_bubble];


bubble.xScale=_bubble.yScale=2;
bubble.alpha=0.5;
```