# Scale a SKPhysicsBody, how?

Tags: sprite-kit, skphysicsbody

I'm reasonably sure I've previously seen code somewhere that scales a SKPhysicsBody, but google and the docs aren't helping, making me more confused than normal.

Is there a way to scale a physic's body in SpriteKit?

The docs, here, don't mention anything about it: https://developer.apple.com/reference/spritekit/skphysicsbody

Comment: I did managed to do that here : http://stackoverflow.com/a/33572073/3402095 using SKActions. Of course that was a brief try, and I haven't tested it much. You could give it a try and come back with results. Also, re-creating a physics body is one way to go...Don't know about performance in that case if there are lot of bodies that should be scaled.

Comment: I really don't want to change, recreate or make new bodies, just scale an existing one. Well, lot's of them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you assign a physics body to a sprite and scale that sprite, the physics body will scale with it.

Comment: I want to scale the physics body, not the sprite.

Comment: You could try adding a 'dummy' node with its alpha set to 0 that has a physics body to the actual node you want displayed, then scale/change the dummy node.

Comment: just use an SKNode, no alpha needed

Answer (score 1):

So the answer I think to your question is a solid "no"; at least not in anything I've seen before.

If you care to dabble in a workaround:

1. Create a new physics body that is larger than what you currently have. Make a method or two to accomplish this.

`node.physicsBody = scaledPhysicsBody(bodyToScale: xxxx)`

2.

I would just make a blank `SKNode` and child it to whatever it is that you want to be hit-detectable. Then get rid of the parent's physics body and just use the child's. Now, you can scale the child node (and thus the PB) without affecting the graphics of the main sprite.

Answer (score 1):

just updating this in 2023:
if you create you physics body from the sprites texture, you can use the SKPhysicsBody initialiser with texture and size property like this:

```
let scale: CGFloat = 0.9
self.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(
     texture: self.texture!,
     size: CGSize(
        width: self.size.width * scale, 
        height:self.size.height * scale
    )
)
```