# Resizing a SpriteKit SKPhysicsBody created with SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius:)

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, skphysicsbody

I am building a SpriteKit "chain reaction" game where circles get larger as they "explode". I am using the `SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius:)` initializer to create physics bodies for the circles.

Unfortunately, these physics bodies don't seem to re-size as the circles get larger, and they don't have an exposed `.radius` property I can set. Is there any way to resize a physics body in SpriteKit, or do I need to create a new physics body every frame instead? (This is what I have done below and the code works fine, but it feels really inefficient to create new physics bodies in update loops.)

PS - I know with circles I can easily do accurate collision detection using trig to get the distances, but I wanted to use SpriteKit collision detection for some other effects.

```
func moveCircles(dt:CGFloat){
   enumerateChildNodesWithName("circle") { node, stop in
     let c = node as! CircleSprite
     var halfWidth = c.size.width / 2.0
     c.update(dt) // in update() exploding circles get larger.
         if c.isExploding{
        // FIXME: Have to make a new physics body every update - I don't like this!
            c.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: halfWidth)
            c.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = CollisionCategories.ExplodingCircle
            c.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = CollisionCategories.Circle
            c.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 0
            c.physicsBody?.dynamic = true // the default
        }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might want to read up more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19305653/skphysicsbody-and-sknode-setscale). Resizing the physicsBody is not possible and it is recommended that you create a new physicsBody and assign it to the node.

Comment: That's what I thought - I was just wondering if there was any way around this. I can't find this fact anywhere in the official Apple documentation, other than this:
 "Very few characteristics of a physics body are fixed. Outside of a physics body’s area, most properties can be changed at any time." 

found at the end of this document: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/SpriteKit_PG/Physics/Physics.html

Comment: how incredibly silly - you can't change the radius of a circle collider!

Comment: @Fattie in fact this makes sense! Resizing a physical body would need to change many of its properties (mass/density/etc), if not it would be too easy to obtain very weird physical effects due to physical body change.

Comment: I can't really agree, @Jean-BaptisteYunès !  consider a 2D physics especially, it is completely normal you change the radius of a "dot" (very likely just setting the mass to say "1" again)

Comment: No mass is related to density and area, etc. This is not so simple, so that it is sufficient to enforce recreating appropriate physical body.