# Change Physical body frame in spritekit

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, game-engine, game-physics

I develop an iOS game using SpriteKit (such a helpful framework to quickly make a game). I add texture and configure a physical body for a main character as image

[image: The first state: Stand Up]

The green rectangle is the frame of the physical body. I'm using the following code to create it

```
@interface MainCharacter : SKSpriteNode

@end

@implementation MainCharacter

+ (instancetype)mainCharacterAtPosition:(CGPoint)pos {
    MainCharacter* mainChar = [[MainCharacter alloc] initWithTexture:[SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"stand_up"]];
    mainChar.position = pos;
    mainChar.xScale = 0.5f;
    mainChar.yScale = 0.5f;

    return mainChar;
}

- (instancetype)initWithTexture:(SKTexture *)texture {
    if (self = [super initWithTexture:texture]) {
        self.name = kCharacterName;

        self.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5f, 0.0f);

        [self standup];

        CGSize spriteSize = self.size;
        CGPoint center = CGPointMake(spriteSize.width*(self.anchorPoint.x-0.5f), spriteSize.height*(0.5f-self.anchorPoint.y));

        self.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:spriteSize center:center];
        self.physicsBody.dynamic = NO;
        self.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = kCharacterCategory;
        self.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = 0x0;
        self.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = 0x0;
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)standup {
    SKAction* standupAction = [SKAction setTexture:self.standupTexture resize:YES];
    [self runAction:standupAction];
}

- (void)standdown {
    SKAction* standownAction = [SKAction setTexture:self.standdownTexture resize:YES];
    [self runAction:standownAction completion:^{

    }];

    [self performSelector:@selector(standup) withObject:nil afterDelay:1.0f];
}
```

MainCharacter is a class that inherits from SKSPriteNode, just an convienient class to manage a main character. Stand Up is a first state of the character. I have another state, temporarily called stand down (demonstrate as following image)

[image: Stand down state]

I add a swipe down gesture to make character stand down.

**The green rectangle also the physical body but it's too large for the character. I want to make a physical body frame as the red rectangle.**

Can anyone help me how to make the physical body smaller when my character stand down and enlarge the physical body after it stands up

Comment: I guess you should re-create a physics body in that case, or use two nodes with different physics bodies and switch between them (one node should be hidden and its category, contact and collision bitmasks will be changed accordingly)

Comment: @Whirlwind, I don't know why but the idea re-create a physical body seems to not work. I complete the task with your second idea (using two nodes and switch between them). Anyway thanks

Comment: Both ways got its pros and cons, but no silver bullet for this. You can't simply resize, or scale physics body dynamically. When you re-creating node's physics body, the only downside is that velocity is lost... More about this : http://stackoverflow.com/a/19415430/3402095 , http://stackoverflow.com/a/21030752/3402095

Answer (score 0):

You can destroy the current physics body `self.physicsBody = nil;` and then simply create a new one with the new size requirements.

Comment: Can you give some code, but it seems to not work, after re-create, the physical body frame seems to be doubled.

Comment: @pf2707 - You can use the same code you use when creating a physics body the first time around. Just change the size to match your need.

Answer (score 0):

I solve this problem by using 2 nodes for 2 states (as a suggestion): stand up state and stand down state. I named it

standupNode and standdownNode

First, add the standupNode to the game scene. If swipe donw gesture recognize, I remove the standupNode from game scene and add the standdownNode instead. On contrary, removing the standdownNode from the game scene then add the standupNode if character stands up

Comment: Doing it as you described will achieve your goal but this approach will not work well if you start having animation sequences for your character. Constantly having to remove and add the player node will make positioning of different sized nodes very difficult.