# Resize SKPhysicsBody edges and keep children inside

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, skphysicsbody, skscene, skphysicsworld

I have a large rectangular `SKPhysicsBody` created with `SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFrom:...)`. Inside that physics body are a bunch of balls that bounce around. When a notification appears, I show a view from the bottom of the screen. I want to resize the `SKPhysicsBody` so the balls bounce off this notification view while it's on screen.

What I do now is

```
func updateWalls() {
    let wallInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(bottomWallInset, 0, 0, 0)
    scene.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFrom:UIEdgeInsetsInsetRect(bounds, wallInsets))
}
```

In other words I just replace the old physics body with a new one with the new dimensions. This works, except that if any balls are **in the region between the old dimensions and the new dimensions** they get trapped and bounce off the outside of the wall and fall out of the world.

Is there an elegant way to animate the transition between the old and new wall bounds, such that any balls that lie at the bottom are "swept" up into the new dimensions, and guaranteed to remain inside the wall? [You can't scale an `SKPhysicsBody` directly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19305653/skphysicsbody-and-sknode-setscale).

Answer (score 1):

In this situation, instead of resizing the physics body, it is probably easier to create a node to represent the notification. That is, make an SKNode that does not render anything, attach a physics body to it the same size as the notification view, and just move the node along with the notification view. You can create an animation for the node movement at the same speed as the view is animated. This should give the effect you need with less possibility of confusing the physics simulation.

Answer (score 0):

`SpriteKit` have always troubles about scaling `SKPhysicsBody`'s, because the physicsBody don't remain the same, there isn't "continuity" between physicsBodies properties. So this is not a good way.

I want to focus your attention on distinguish between nodes and physicsBodies: you could build 2 walls with it's `physicsBody` and when you don't need one of them you could make `ishidden = true` to hide the node and set `isDynamic = false` to disable the physics interactions.
So , one time you have the interior wall with it's body, after you can hide the interior , disable the physics interactions and enable the external wall with it's physics.

About the transition between the old and new wall bounds you can study an animation between the two nodes.

Comment: Thanks for the help. The transition between the two physicsBodies would be the same as what I have now, where I just replace one with the other. I'm still stuck on how to do the animation though.

Comment: Try to turn off the physicsBody to the internal node, then use the internal node to make the animation and to become like the external wall (but without physicsBody) and hide it at the end ( so show the external node). After all, report the hidden internal node to it's original dimension