# iOS: Implementing user-controlled camera "zoom" with Sprite Kit

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, sprite-kit

I have a working **2D platformer** engine that wraps Sprite Kit. To implement a scrolling world<strike>, I'm **following Apple's guidance** in their Advanced Scene Processing documentation</strike>: My scene contains a world; the world contains all nodes, including a camera node.

Now I'm making the level editor, and that's also working just fine. Here's my problem: **I can't figure out how to "zoom the camera in and out"** within the level editor.

I searched and **found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19087392/spritekit-set-scale-and-physics) on Stack Overflow**. <strike>Using DogCoffee's answer,</strike> I was able to implement zoom behavior that appeared correct but caused incorrect sprite node positions (in my editor, when zoomed in or out, I can no longer select sprites).

**How should I be zooming my camera?** Or, how should I be adjusting my object positions following a zoom operation?

If you have a tested solution, I'm all ears. I mean...eyes. Yeah.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<strike>Ok, this is what happens when you ignore answers with a lower score.</strike> Revisiting the same question I linked to, above, I tried JKallio's answer and got it working.

Here's a quick rundown of my implementation (reworked to be free of my personal class names):

**In my UI manager:**

```
- (IBAction)pressedZoomIn:(id)sender
{
  CGFloat newZoom = [EditorState zoom] - 0.1f;
  [EditorState setZoom:newZoom];
  [EditorState currentScene].size = CGSizeMake([EditorState currentScene].size.width * newZoom, 
                                               [EditorState currentScene].size.height * newZoom);
}
- (IBAction)pressedZoomOut:(id)sender
{
  CGFloat newZoom = [EditorState zoom] + 0.1f;
  [EditorState setZoom:newZoom];
  [EditorState currentScene].size = CGSizeMake([EditorState currentScene].size.width * newZoom, 
                                               [EditorState currentScene].size.height * newZoom);
}
```

This solution does give you some "inertia" on your zoom control, but it works for what I'm doing.

Comment: So I suggest you make one change in that you save the initial scene size and when applying the zoom you multiply against the initial scene size. Otherwise the size can really get away from you.