# SpriteKit - Animating the scale of a SKScene has no effect

Tags: sprite-kit, skscene

By implementing the following code I receive the following error message:

SKScene: Animating the scale of a SKScene has no effect.

```
_popup = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"popup.png"];
[_popup.texture setFilteringMode:SKTextureFilteringNearest];
_popup.position =  CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width/2, self.frame.size.width);
[self addChild:_popup];
SKAction *appear = [SKAction scaleTo:1.6 duration:0.5];
SKAction *wait = [SKAction waitForDuration:10.0];
SKAction *disappear = [SKAction scaleTo:0.0 duration:0.5];
SKAction *removeFromParent = [SKAction removeFromParent];
SKAction *sequence = [SKAction sequence:@[appear, wait, disappear, removeFromParent, [SKAction runBlock:^{
    [self newScene];
}]]];
[self runAction:sequence];
```

Do you have ideas?

**EDIT**

This is the working code:

```
_popup = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"popup.png"];
_popup.position =  CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width/2, self.frame.size.width);
[self addChild:_popup];
SKAction *appear = [SKAction scaleTo:1.6 duration:0.5];
SKAction *wait = [SKAction waitForDuration:5.0];
SKAction *disappear = [SKAction scaleTo:0.0 duration:0.5];
SKAction *remove = [SKAction removeFromParent];
SKAction *rblock = [SKAction runBlock:^{ [self newScene]; }];
SKAction *sequence = [SKAction sequence:@[appear, wait, disappear, rblock, remove]];
[_popup runAction:sequence];
```

It is important to put "rblock" before of "remove" and change "[self runAction:sequence];" with "[_popup runAction:sequence];". That's all!

Comment: possible duplicate of [SpriteKit - Set Scale and Physics](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19087392/spritekit-set-scale-and-physics)

Comment: I have seen that solution but it does not run with my code (IMHO).

Comment: What is the scaleMode set to for your scene ?

Comment: SKSceneScaleModeAspectFit